# C# - Add values to a string array unless they are NULL

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, combobox

I'm populating a `ComboBox` with a list of values taken from four text boxes that are in a 'configuration' form. The code works, but the issue I have is that it is acceptable for some of these text boxes to be blank. If any of the text boxes are empty, then I have empty spaces in my `ComboBox` list. My code:

```
comboFms.Items.Clear();
string[] fmsDB = new string[] { "Select FMS Database", fms1, fms2, fms3, fms4 };
comboFms.Items.AddRange(fmsDB);
this.cboFms.Text = "Select FMS Database";
this.cboFms.Enabled = true;
```

In this example, only `fms1` has a value. This results in the dropdown list displaying like so:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way I can exclude the blank values from my string array or ComboBox?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could replace the `comboFms.Items.AddRange(fmsDB);` with:

```
Using System.Linq;

...

comboFms.Items.AddRange(fmsDB.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've tried adjusting my code per your suggestion, however it does not appear to work and returns a debug error regrading String[] not containing a definition for 'Where'.

Comment: @Rawns Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file

Comment: Do'h! Just realised this! Thanks @pinkfloydx33! :)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thank you for your contribution.